# Java application and web commands

Tags: java, web, websocket, server

So I need to have a Java application running as a server so it can recieve commands. But I also want to have an intranet webpage so I can control de application. What is the best you to achive this?

Is it websockets? or is there any other better alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop a Java web application and use Tomcat or other container. Expose REST APIs or use websocket to develop your commands. Build html/Javascript UI to use those services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So I think I will go with REST. thanks.